# $ \int_1^2\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4 $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$I=  \int_1^2\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_1^2  \frac{x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4$$

---

**Answer Options:**

1. $1$
2. $\frac{1}{2}$
3. $\frac{1}{3}$
4. $\frac{1}{4}$

I need some suggestion here. I tried to evaluate one by one but it becomes messy. I think there some trick involved here.

Comment: Maple answers $\frac 1 2$.

Comment: Using $\dfrac{X-x_4}{X+x_4}=1-2\dfrac{x_4}{X+x_4}$ could be the start.

Comment: Hint: the answer is the same for any of the 4 possible positions of the minus sign in the numerator. Now add up those 4 functions...

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh plz show ur answer

Comment: @Foggy: you asked for a trick, and I gave you one. I don't want to give you a complete solution; you should try to work it out for yourself!

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh its not clear what u mean. Which fxns to add?

Comment: See Timbuc's edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An idea:

Since

$$\frac x{x+a}=1-\frac a{x+a}$$

we get that

$$\int_1^2\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1=\int_1^2\left(1-\frac{x_2+x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}+\frac{x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+\ldots+x_4}\right)dx_1=$$

$$1-2x_4\int_1^2\frac{dx_1}{x_1+\ldots+x_4}=1-2x_4\log\frac{2+x_2+x_3+x_4}{1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$$

Try now with this the following iterations.

**Another idea:** Using Asal's *very* good comment:

Suppose

$$S=\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4$$

As noted in the comment by Asal, the result is the same when we interchange the minus sign in the numerator among the different variables, because of symmetry, so if we call $\;A_i\;$ the multiple integral with the minus sign before $\;x_i\;$ in the numerator, we get

$$4S=A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4=2\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4=$$

$$=2\implies S=\frac12$$

Comment: I showed the complete solution with Asal's excellent hint since you already knew the answer.

Comment: So if you go from $4$ to $N$, you get $\dfrac{2}{N}$?

Comment: I've no idea what is N in your question and how is it related to what I did in my answer, @NikolajK

Comment: @NikolajK: no, you get a different multiple on top. So you end up with $(N-2)/N$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Timbuc, the interchange of sign made no change in result. Was this because all limits were from 1 to 2?

Comment: The trick in the second version works not only for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$, but for $\sum_{k=1}^Nx_k$. In fact, you don't even use $x_k$, it seems to work for $\sum_{k=1}^Nf(x_k)$ where $f$ is any function. And you can also prove a variation of it where more than just one sign is flipped.

Comment: @Foggy Indeed so: both the limits and the $\;4$ - variable function are to "blame" for the symmetry in this case.

Comment: @NikolajK Yes, I think so, since in the last equality we get the multiple integral of $\;1\;$ ...of course, $\;f(x)=0\;$ is out of the question, and see the comment by Asal below your question.

Comment: K, so ${\large\large\int}_a^b\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^mf(x_i)-\sum_{j=m+1}^Nf(x_j)}{\sum_{l=1}^Nf(x_l)}\prod_{k=1}^N{\mathrm{d}x_k}$ is some simple rational number.

Comment: @NikolajK It would be nice of u, if u plz mention any variation of this trick

Comment: @Timbuc so is it that if we interchange the sign of $x_1$ to $-x_1$ and $x_4$ to $-x_4$ so does it becomes $\int_1^2\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \frac{-x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}{-x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}d(-x_1)dx_2dx_3d(-x_4)$, so assuming $x_1=-t_1$ and $x_4=-t_4$, do we get $\int_{-1}^{-2}\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_{-1}^{-2} \frac{t_1+x_2+x_3-t_4}{t_1+x_2+x_3+t_4}dt_1dx_2dx_3dt_4                             =\int_1^2\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_1^2 \frac{t_1+x_2+x_3-t_4}{t_1+x_2+x_3+t_4}dt_1dx_2dx_3dt_4 =\int_2^1\int_1^2 \int_1^2 \int_2^1 \frac{t_1+x_2+x_3-t_4}{t_1+x_2+x_3+t_4}dt_1dx_2dx_3dt_4$ ? Please clarify