# Multiple Integral Puzzle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2\int_1^2 {{x_1+x_2+x_3-x_4}\over{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}} \,dx_1\,dx_2\,dx_3\,dx_4$$

$I=1/2$  or  $1/3$ or $1/4$ or $1$ ?
 [from ISI-Kolkatta Sample papers]

I know that there must be a really clever trick to get this one. Just not able to see it. Any **hint** will be really useful for me.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131769/int-12-int-12-int-12-int-12-fracx-1x-2x-3-x-4x-1x-2x-3x-4dx-1?rq=1

Comment: How do I close this ? I have found that this is a duplicate .